# The execution time of the selection sort is weird

Tags: python, sorting

I don't know why function 2 is faster than function 1
func2 is very fast
Is there a mistake?

func1

```
def selection_sort(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < arr[min_idx]:
                min_idx = j
        arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]
```

func2

```
def selectionSort(arr : list, n : int) : #n=len(arr)
    if n>0 :
        m = min(arr[0:n])
        arr.remove(m)
        arr.append(m)
        selectionSort(arr,n-1)
```

I thought the results would be similar, but after sorting for 100 lists with size 10000, func2 was 52 seconds, func1 was 625 seconds.

Comment: Your recursive implementation will not work with a list of 10,000 elements

Comment: @DarkKnight it will if you set `sys.setrecursionlimit(11000)` (or anything >10000) (Not saying it is a good implementation).

Comment: @matszwecja Of course that is true but OP hasn't done that

Comment: He didn't show how he run the function, and he provided the results of supposed testing with n=10000, so it's a fair assumption that he did something like that.

Comment: @matszwecja I doubt everything she says. For example, with a correctly implemented selection sort, 100 lists each containing 10,000 pseudo-randomly chosen values can all be sorted in less than 3 minutes

Comment: @DarkKnight I just run both functions with random lists of those sizes and the runtimes are 120s for f1 and 60s for f2. If he guessed those results, he's pretty damned good at guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for the significant difference in the runtimes is the way you are choosing a minimal value - Python's built-in `min` is significantly faster than manual iteration over each element of the list.

```
import random
import time

list_count = 100
list_size = 10**5

def min_1(arr):
    min_idx = 0
    for j in range(1, len(arr)):
        if arr[j] < arr[min_idx]:
            min_idx = j
    return arr[min_idx]

def min_2(arr : list):
    return min(arr)

test1 = [[random.randint(0, 1000) for _ in range(list_size)] for _ in range(list_count)]

t1 = time.monotonic()
res1 = [min_1(el) for el in test1]
t2 = time.monotonic()
res2 = [min_2(el) for el in test1]
t3 = time.monotonic()
print(f"f1 exec time = {t2 - t1}s")
print(f"f2 exec time = {t3 - t2}s")
```

Running above code, you can see that `min` is about 5 times as fast as explicit loop. And because finding the minimal value is a significant part of selection sort, that might be *one* of the reasons for time difference.

That being said, using recursion as in the 2nd code is probably not the best way to go. As discussed by @DarkKnight, Python's default recursion limit is 1000 and without changing it, such a program will not work for any list bigger than 1000 elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your function

```
def selection_sort_old(arr: list):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        min_idx = i
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < arr[min_idx]:
                min_idx = j
        arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]
```

You compare arr[j] with arr[min_idx]. Indexing the arr with min_idx takes a bit of time, so moving this out of the "for j" loop comparison will slightly reduce your execution time (around 16% shorter in my test case):

```
def selection_sort_faster(arr: list):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        min_idx = i
        m = arr[min_idx]
        for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
            if arr[j] < m:
                min_idx = j
                m = arr[min_idx]
        arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]
```

Another point is that the functionality you have written for finding the smallest element is probably less efficient than the built in min() function, because this is written in c. Using the min function like this will improve the speed, but it will still not be as fast as the func 2 you provided. This is because time is spent finding the index of the min value.

```
def selection_sort_faster2(arr: list, n: int):
    for i in range(n):
        m = min(arr[i:n])
        min_idx = arr.index(m)
        arr[i], arr[min_idx] = arr[min_idx], arr[i]
```

This implementation is about 7% slower than the func2 you provided though. Ideally, you would get the index of the smallest element directly and use that in the swap operations.